# How the find the mod n if ab = 1 mod n? Need Help with RSA cryptography questions.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

Numbers have each been encoded using RSA with a modulus of $m = p q = 496241$ (with
$p$ and $q$ being primes) and encoding exponent of $218821$.

You are advised that $\{13631, 142703\}$ is a valid encoding–decoding pair for the same modulus, $m$.

$(a)$ Use this information to determine $\phi(m)$ for this modulus.
(Using software to directly factorise m is not a valid option for doing this part.)

$de = 1 \pmod{\phi(m)}$, right? So in this case: $13631\times 142703 1 \pmod {\phi(m)}$. Am I right so far? How do I calculate what the mod is, and therefore what $\phi(m)$ is?

$(b)$ Verify your answer by determining the primes $p$ and $q$.
Show how these combine to give both $m$ and $\phi(m)$.

$(c)$ Calculate the decoding exponent for $218821$, as encoding exponent, using the extended Euclidean
algorithm. (Again, using software to directly obtain this is not a valid option, though you are
welcome to use software to confirm your answer.)

$(d)$ For each of the $12$ numbers in your message, verify they have no prime factors in common with $m$.
(It is OK to use software for this task, provided you have answered the previous part.)

Comment: If $ab=1\pmod n$, then $ab-1=kn$, so you only need to factorize $ab-1$ to find possible values of $n$.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: @KennyLau could you please explain further? So I factorise (13631∗142703)-1, then what?

Comment: @AlonzoRobbe then you just pick a factor to be $n$.

Comment: @KennyLau doesn't work that way, there is a proper algorithm that does not rely on factorisation. Moreover $ed-1$ is a multiple of $\phi(n)$ not of $n$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I'm just responding to the title.

Comment: @KennyLau he states it correctly in the body, though.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6361/is-sharing-the-modulus-for-multiple-rsa-key-pairs-secure) describes the algorithm to find $\phi(m)$ from a pair $(e,d)$, like your $(e,d) = (13631, 142703)$

Copying, using $N$ instead of your $m$ as notation for the modulus:

1. Compute $k = ed-1$
2. Determine the exponent of $2$, $t$, in the factorization of $k$,
   i.e. factor $k$ into the form $k = 2^t r$ with $t > 0$ and $r$ odd.
3. Pick a random $x\,|\,2 \leq x < N$
4. Compute the sequence
   $s = x^{\frac k 2}, x^{\frac k 4}, \dots, x^{\frac k {2^t}} \pmod{N}$
5. Determine the first index $i$ such that $s_i \neq \pm 1$ and
   $s_{i-1} = 1$

   - If no such index exists, choose a new $x$ and try again.
   - Otherwise, let $p = \gcd(s_i - 1, N)$ and $q = \frac N p$.
6. Done.

This is doable by hand calculator for these sizes (you might have to try a few $x$). But given the context probably not what your professor intended.

An alternative, directly following the hint:

By definition of RSA: $ed = 1 \pmod{\phi(m)}$. So $ed-1 $ is a multiple of $\phi(m)$. Now for the given pair $(e,d)$:

$ed -1 =1945184592$ , which we can divide by factors of 2,
leaving $121574037$, which is divisible by 3, using the standard test
and leaves us with $13508226$, this turns out to be divisble by $13$ (after trying $7$ and $11$) leaving $3117283$ also divisible by $13$, and we are left with $239791$. Then (e.g. checking all primes $< 100$) we find a factor $61$ which leaves $3931$ (which is prime, checking all primes $\sqrt{3931}$ as divisors). So

$$ed-1 = 2^4 \cdot 3 \cdot 13^2 \cdot 61 \cdot 3931$$ and we now we can find $\phi(m)$ because $ed-1$ happens to have a lot of small factors, and we don't have to find $\phi(m)$ by guessing it or something like that. $\phi(m)= (p-1)(q-1)$ should be divisible by $2^2$ at least (as $p,q$ are odd) and we note that $t= \frac{ed-1}{3931} = 494832$ seems a strong candidate for being $\phi(m)$ as it is $< m$ and has the same length and the same starting digits (which we expect, as $p, q$ are around size $\sqrt{m}$ so $m - \phi(m)$ is about 1400 to 1500. So we expect the first two digits to coincide, which rules out the candidates $39131 \cdot 61$ or $2 \cdot 3931 \cdot 61 = 479582$.

The algorithm I gave first will always work (with probability close to $1$), regardless of being able to factor $ed-1$ an this *could* be as hard as factoring $m$ itself. So this exercise is somewhat misleading, as here we are "lucky" with our $ed-1$ having a relatively small factor 61.

For (b) note that $m - \phi(m)  =pq -(p-1)(q-1)$ = $p+q-1$,and the left hand side is known as $m$ and $\phi(m)$ are. So we know $p+q$ and $pq$ from which we solve $p$ and $q$ in a standard way (quadratic equation).