# How to factorise large number without calculator?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, cryptography, prime-factorization

I would like to factorise $496241$. I know the answer is $677 \times 733$. But I don't know how to get there.

Here is the full question:

"A message has been encoded using RSA with a modulus of $m = p q = 496241$ (with
$p$ and $q$ being primes) and encoding exponent of $218821$.

You are advised that $\{13631, 142703\}$ is a valid encoding–decoding pair for the same modulus, $m$.

(a) Use this information to determine $\phi(m)$ for this modulus.
(Using software to directly factorise $m$ is not a valid option for doing this part.)

(b) Verify your answer by determining the primes $p$ and $q$.
Show how these combine to give both $m$ and $\phi(m)$."

I need it so I can solve (a), and it says I cannot use software to directly factorise m. So I guess pen and paper. But there are not tutorial online. Thanks

Comment: That's the entire concept of RSA. There are no (efficient) algorithms to find prime decompositions! Probably, the question is made so you realise this.

Comment: "I need it so I can solve (a)". No, you don't. What you need is the information you have been given. I'm sure Ross has done examples like this in his lectures.

Comment: It's not about not using software, it's about using an approach based on the knowledge of ($e,d,m$) rather than using a general-purpose algorithm that only needs $m$ as input.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2309064/4280

Comment: You're in the same class as Alonzo Robbe?

Comment: @Henno, I'm teaching that class with a colleague.

Answer (score 4):

[This answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6361/is-sharing-the-modulus-for-multiple-rsa-key-pairs-secure) describes the algorithm to find $\phi(m)$ from a pair $(e,d)$, like your $(e,d) = (13631, 142703)$

Copying, using $N$ instead of your $m$ as notation for the modulus:

1. Compute $k = ed-1$
2. Determine the exponent of $2$, $t$, in the factorization of $k$,
   i.e. factor $k$ into the form $k = 2^t r$ with $t > 0$ and $r$ odd.
3. Pick a random $x\,|\,2 \leq x < N$
4. Compute the sequence
   $s = x^{\frac k 2}, x^{\frac k 4}, \dots, x^{\frac k {2^t}} \pmod{N}$
5. Determine the first index $i$ such that $s_i \neq \pm 1$ and
   $s_{i-1} = 1$

   - If no such index exists, choose a new $x$ and try again.
   - Otherwise, let $p = \gcd(s_i - 1, N)$ and $q = \frac N p$.
6. Done.

This is doable by hand calculator for these sizes (you might have to try a few $x$). But given the context probably not what your professor intended.

An alternative, directly following the hint:

By definition of RSA: $ed = 1 \pmod{\phi(m)}$. So $ed-1 $ is a multiple of $\phi(m)$. Now for the given pair $(e,d)$:

$ed -1 =1945184592$ , which we can divide by factors of 2,
leaving $121574037$, which is divisible by 3, using the standard test
and leaves us with $13508226$, this turns out to be divisble by $13$ (after trying $7$ and $11$) leaving $3117283$ also divisible by $13$, and we are left with $239791$. Then (e.g. checking all primes $< 100$) we find a factor $61$ which leaves $3931$ (which is prime, checking all primes $\sqrt{3931}$ as divisors). So

$$ed-1 = 2^4 \cdot 3 \cdot 13^2 \cdot 61 \cdot 3931$$ and we now we can find $\phi(m)$ because $ed-1$ happens to have a lot of small factors, and we don't have to find $\phi(m)$ by guessing it or something like that. $\phi(m)= (p-1)(q-1)$ should be divisible by $2^2$ at least (as $p,q$ are odd) and we note that $t= \frac{ed-1}{3931} = 494832$ seems a strong candidate for being $\phi(m)$ as it is $< m$ and has the same length and the same starting digits (which we expect, as $p, q$ are around size $\sqrt{m}$ so $m - \phi(m)$ is about 1400 to 1500. So we expect the first two digits to coincide, which rules out the candidates $39131 \cdot 61$ or $2 \cdot 3931 \cdot 61 = 479582$.

The algorithm I gave first will always work (with probability close to $1$), regardless of being able to factor $ed-1$ an this *could* be as hard as factoring $m$ itself. So this exercise is somewhat misleading, as here we are "lucky" with our $ed-1$ having a relatively small factor 61.

For (b) note that $m - \phi(m)  =pq -(p-1)(q-1)$ = $p+q-1$,and the left hand side is known as $m$ and $\phi(m)$ are. So we know $p+q$ and $pq$ from which we solve $p$ and $q$ in a standard way (quadratic equation).

Comment: Thanks so much. Im having some trouble with (b). Mainly the quadratic equation. If Im doing it correctly, I am not getting the correct numbers. Would you mind explaining a bit further on how to get $p$ and $q$. Ive gotten $p + q = 256451$

Comment: I had a look at your edit, and Im afraid Im still not getting the correct answer. Or im not doing something correctly. Now, I have $p+q=16660$. But solving the quad eqn $p^2 -16660p+496241=0$ isnt giving me a nice answer. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Have you checked my factoring of $ed-1$? I might have a calculating mistake.

Comment: Yes, double checked it. It is correct. the Factoring of $ed-1$. I still dont have the values for $p$ and $q$

Comment: Also, the answer for $p$ and $q$ should be $677$ and $733$, as $677*733=496241$. Therefore $\phi(m)$ should be $676*732=494832$. But that is not attainable.

Comment: It does check out that $ed-1$ is divisble by $494832$, with quotient $3931$, which is prime. So I don't see a way to get the correct $\phi(m)$ from $ed-1$, except by the first algorithm.

Comment: $ed-1 = 2^4 \cdot 3\cdot 13^2 \cdot 61 \cdot 3931$ as a prime factorisation. $\phi(m) = 2^4 \cdot 3 \cdot 13^2 \cdot 61$. So one should spot a factor $61$ in $239791$. (maybe trying all primes less than a hundred?)

Answer (score 1):

Although the comment pointing out that factoring numbers is hard in general is correct, that doesn't mean some numbers aren't slightly more easily factored.

In this case $496241 = 705^2 - 28^2 = (705+28)(705-28) = 677*733$ as desired.

Note that I'm pretty sure I couldn't have spotted this without having the answer, but it does at least potentially provide a route to the correct factorisation.

------ Edited to correct answer ------

Comment: There is no way you would have spotted that!

Comment: On the other hand, when one has reason to expect two close primes as factors, trying a little Fermat factorisation is not a far-fetched idea.

Comment: I’m not so sure it would be hard to spot. $\lceil \sqrt{496241}\rceil=705$ means $705^2$ is the smallest (larger) square to try using if you want to write $496241$ as a difference of squares, and $705^2-496241=784=28^2.$

Comment: @SteveKass Would this work for any large number N, or does it does happen to work out this way for specifically for 496241?

Comment: @J.Doe This only works if $p,q$ are too close together. It's especially bad if you use twin primes $p,q=p+2$, as then $p,q$ are just 1 away from $\sqrt{pq}$ . So in practice one makes sure that $p,q$ are far enough apart.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that you know that you can stop at the square root.  If you have not found a factor by then, you won't.

If you want to produce a list of prime numbers then the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is good though it is not so good for just testing one number.

Comment: The question is about using the additional knowledge of one encoding-decoding pair to simplify the process of factoring.

Comment: I was just addressing the question implied by the first sentence.  I was trying to suggest how to factor it with fairly low tech tools.  The square root of 496241 is 704 and a bit which can be figured out fairly easily.  Eratosthenes will give you a list of primes up to that fairly quickly.  If you are woking by hand, the effort of creating that list could pay off by saving quite a few divisions.