# Find a prime factor of $7999973$ without a calculator

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

How would you go about finding prime factors of a number like $7999973$? I have trivial knowledge about divisor-searching algorithms.

Comment: This is the only context you have to solve the problem. Find a prime factor of 7999973 without a calculator. I got this problem from an old problem book, but there is no explanation or further context.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't read the question carefully... or perhaps you didn't write the question carefully.  Finding prime factors (implicitly: all prime factors) of the number, without a calculator, is going to be quite hard.  Finding **a** prime factor (that is: only one asked for), as in your title, is quite easy in this case.

Comment: @David: `7999973` is the product of two primes. Finding one prime factor will give you the other. You're right though, it will be hard to prove that the largest one is prime.

Comment: If ever I could understand what is special with this question and such votes

Comment: Those who don't understand this problem might understand it more if they assumed that it's a problem that is meant to be solvable in a reasonable amount of time. When you take that approach, it's safe to assume there must be some trick or non-linear thinking, as the answer confirms.

Comment: @EricDuminil That's exactly my point.  There is no way **easily and without a calculator** to know that this number is a product of two primes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to factorise large number without calculator?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2309238/how-to-factorise-large-number-without-calculator)

Comment: As indicated in the other comments, if you are expected to do it by hand in a reasonably short amount of time (e.g. on a single piece of paper) then there must be some special property of the number that makes it easy , In this case it's the difference of 2 cubes.   In general you need to test divisibility of $n$ by every prime not exceeding $\sqrt n\;$  to find whether $n$ is, or is not, prime.

Answer (score 212):

The thing to notice here is that 7,999,973 is close to 8,000,000.  In fact it is $8000000 - 27$.  Both of these are perfect cubes.  Differences of cubes always factor: $$a^3 - b^3 = (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$$

Here we have $a=200, b=3$, so $a-b= 197$ is a factor.

Comment: And Pari says the other is $40609$.

Comment: @Bernard: Also note that this method does not prove that the factors we got are prime.

Comment: @user21820 As clarified in a comment, the original question only required finding *a* prime factor, and 197 is small enough to check by hand.

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent: Yup I know that 197 is prime; I'm just stating for the record that this method in general does not say anything about primality.

Comment: @user21820 well it gives you a relatively small factor (compared to 7.999.973), and then you could still divide this one by any of its factors until you got a prime

Comment: @Rafalon trying to divide by 7, 11 and 13 is enough (for 197).

Comment: @WillNess that's exactly my point :)

Comment: @MJD Love your answer but why exactly did you choose 8 million as your starting point.. Too satisfy the two wo perfect cubes ? or a deeper theory?

Comment: @PeterH Because the original number was suspiciously close to $8\,000\,000$, with all those $9$'s, so he checked to see whether it worked, and it did. It's a standard type of problem, although in my experience, powers of $10$ are more common as starting points for these problems than numbers like eight million.